# Can Andriod Studio 2.3.3 support new feature, Fonts in XML, which lets you use fonts as resources? I am working on Mac OS

Tags: android, xml, fonts

I followed each and every step given on 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

I am not able to create Font resource file at the following step - 
Right-click the font folder and go to New > Font resource file. The New Resource File window appears.

I am doubtful now, whether I can assign fonts in XML in Android Studio 2.3.3

my build.gradle is as follows

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.crescomobilitysolution.navigationdrawerexercise"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: not supported in **2.3.3** try to update to latest vesion **3.0.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it s supported in Android Studio 3.0 and over